# snowpack Package "abstracts/variables" not found. Have you installed it? getting this error while running npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, abstract, snowpack

I got this error while running npm start
used snowpack.dev https://www.snowpack.dev/

[snow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7qTr.jpg)

```
[snowpack] ! updating dependencies...
[snowpack] ! installing dependencies…
[snowpack] Package "abstracts/variables" not found. Have you installed it?
[snowpack] Install failed.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `snowpack dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-15T12_18_05_035Z-debug.log
PS G:\antonio\projects\react\app>
```

Comment: Have you run `npm install abstracts/variables`?

Answer (score 0):

## Are you using `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json`?

If you are importing `./src/abstracts` as `abstracts/[whateverfile]` via the `baseUrl` configuration, you will need to setup an alias ([Docs here](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#alias)) in your snowpack configuration file.

1. Create `snowpack.config.js` if you have not already done so. Place it in the root of your application, alongside your `package.json`.
2. In `snowpack.config.js`, add:

```
module.exports = {

    ...

    alias: {
        abstracts: '/src/abstracts',
        // continue for remaining directories in /src
    },

    ...

}
```